# Are the Office Web Components going to work in IE9?

Tags: cross-browser, office-web-components

Are the Office Web Components going to work in IE9, FF4, etc?  Modern Browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Web_Components), Office Web Components are implemented as ActiveX controls. Therefore they will **only** work in Internet Explorer.